# porting: Android/Linux client/server socket communication issue

Tags: android, linux, sockets, android-ndk, porting

I'm porting a Server/Client socket application from Windows to Linux/Android and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Basically, what the Client does is send a string of chars to the Server and the Server uppercases the string and then echoes the string back to the Client, which prints out the result.  Somewhere between the Server echoing the uppercased string and the Client receiving the result, there's an error but I can't quite figure it out even with a debugger or Wireshark.

strace of Server:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9099), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(3, 5)                            = 0
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [134515712])         = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
select(0, [], NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

strace of Client:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9099), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9099), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
send(3, "four score and seven years ago\0\0"..., 128, 0) = 128
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
select(0, [], NULL, NULL, {1, 0})       = 0 (Timeout)
write(2, "Exception code: 00000507, data: "..., 52Exception code: 00000507, data: 00000000 ((null):0)
) = 52
shutdown(3, 2 /* send and receive */)   = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the first argument to the select() api call was supposed to contain the [highest socket FD value + 1] on Linux.